# Selected Navigation Menu

Tags: html, css

If you go to http://drupal.org/home, you'll see a navigation towards the top.  When you're on the page, it has it white, but when you go to a different page, the tab changes.  How do you change the class?  Does it involve PHP, jQuery, etc?

Comment: It can be done with CSS or javascript. This link will get you started. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403138/highlighting-an-active-tab-css

Answer (score 0):

If the tab redirects the user to a different url location you can add an id to the `body` of each page and use css to style it based on what page you are:

```
<body id="about">
.
.
.
<li id="about_menu"><a href="#">About</a></li>

#about #about_menu { color: red; }
```

If the tab is loaded with ajax or controlled with jQuery on the same page you can simply set a `.current` class on the element and style it in css.